# What Information does the phase of a cross power spectra give me?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, cross-correlation

I obtain the cross power spectra by the following steps:

1. compute the FFT of signal A and B
2. Multiply A with the conjugate of B store it in C (cross power spectra)
3. Now looking at the Phase of this cross power spectra C, what all information can I deduce about the two signals A and B?

Answer (score 3):

If the two signal show a significant correlation at some frequency $f$ then the phase measured in the cross spectrum gives you the phase lag of the signals at that frequency.

So, take $$ A = \sin(2\pi f t ) $$ and $$ B = \sin(2\pi f t - \phi) $$ then the cross spectral phase at frequency $f$ will give you $\phi$.

Comment: Do you mean the slope of the phase curve across the bandwidth or the phase of individual frequencies?

Comment: @VivekVK - I mean the phase of the individual frequency bins. If your signal spans a bandwidth of frequency bins, you'd have to average the phases of those bins.